# Is there a way to analyze Chromecast crashes?

Tags: google-cast

Obviously, after the crash Developer tools at port 9222 is of no use, because "Remote debugging has been terminated with reason: websocket_closed". How can I retrieve, for example, recorded timeline; or get call stack; or find anything about the reason the Chromecast decided to reboot itself? What are the best (or, for that matter, any) approach to debug Chromecast crashes?

Comment: Do you have a reproducible scenario?

Comment: Well, I suspect that this might be a result of a well documented memory leak in Google Maps API - which is the main engine of the receiver code of my GR8CTZ for Chromecast game. However this might be just my wishful thinking and in reality this is some bad code in my JS. I can do pretty long debugging session stepping through suspicious places in my code, recording and checking timeline from time to time - and then all of a sudden I am getting websocket_closed. The same Chromecast reboot also happens without debugging. I am trying my to react gracefully in the sender - but it doesn't help user

Comment: If I recall correctly, there is a leak when the debugger is connected, so having that connected for a long time can be a source of crash itself. Does your crash happen without debugger connected?

Comment: Yes, Chromecast crashes without debugger connected as well. And in the result of similar behavior - the game is probabilistic in nature, so I can't reproduce the exact point, but if I "walk" in Street View long enough the Chromecast would always crash. This never happens in purely Web version of the game when played in PC or  Android browser, it often happens with Web version played on iPhone. So my suspicions about memory leak have some grounds. But I am at lost as how to prove or disprove them.

Comment: Is this a publicly available app?

Comment: Yes. It was the first published Chromecast game (after Tic-Tac-Toe): https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.palagraph.gr8ctz

Comment: And how should one reproduce the crash?

Comment: The crash is when you "walk" long enough. Each step forward (or backward) loads the new Street View panorama, and after some steps the Chromecast will crash. Either it is because Google Map API doesn't do GC correctly (there is open issue https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3803); or it may be that my code doesn't behave correctly in some border case I can't figure out.

Comment: How long a walk (or how many steps) should one take to see the crash?

Comment: It depends. Sometimes a dozen is enough. I just tried it again (it happened to be Red Square in Moscow) and it took about 40 before it crashed. (Because of that the game is generally playable, even if it doesn't provide consistent experience. In the update I am working on now I am trying to make "long walks" less often needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to look at your log file to see what is causing the crash. It is relatively easy to do that but we need some help from your side.

- First, open the Chromecast setup app on, say, your Android device and go to the settings for your device. You should see a check box that states something like: "Send Chromecast usage data and crash reports to Google". If it is not checked, make sure you check it and then wait 15 minutes or so and reboot your chromecast.
- Try to recreate issue and as soon as it crashes and reboots itself, open the setup app again and select "Submit feedback report" from the overflow menu. You will see a new window on your phone and make sure you enter the following text in the text box there "crash-vmt". We will be using this text to search among the reports that we receive to identify your log.

After doing that, please let us know (add a comment here) so we can grab the log for further investigation.

Comment: Thanks, Ali. Just submitted the feedback report after crash.

Comment: Yes, log shows memory exhaustion (I found two logs from you, one right after the first one).

Comment: Thank you. No call trace or any other details available , I guess?

Comment: There is a lot of low level information in there but nothing that could be much of help to you. Can you run that on a desktop chrome and profile that to get a better feel for what is leaking or how you can address that? I have not run your application so I don't know if this makes sense or not but if you can have lower resolution images, you can try that too.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, Ali. I'll continue investigate.