# How can mere mortals examine chromecast crash reports

Tags: chromecast, crash-reports, google-cast

I am working on a chromecast app. Unfortunately the app and the remote debugger hang after a minute or two. After that point the only thing that can be done is to restart the device (or wait for a minute or two longer and then the device restarts itself).

Can I get my hands on any crash report or resource usage statistics or anything that would give me a clue as to what is actually going on.

This question: [Is there a way to analyze Chromecast crashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491574/is-there-a-way-to-analyze-chromecast-crashes) advises to send the crash report to google and ask them to inspect it for me. But I don't want that. I want to inspect it myself. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the only way to access and inspect that is to follow what was suggested in that post.